# ASP.NET How to bind data in DropDownList outside GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a web aplication to access data in a SQL Server 2008 database. I show the data in a Gridview and I can succesfully edit the rows (even with DropDownLists), but I want to implement the edit of those records with a modal dialog/popup using Bootstrap.

However, I can not get working these DropDownLists in this modal, because resides in a DIV outside the `<asp:GridView>` element. I can bind others text fields in the modal dialog, with this code (the modal dialog is fired with a command ) [code_behind]:

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("editRecord"))
{
    GridViewRow gvrow = GridView2.Rows[index];
    txtRUT.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[2].Text);//.ToString();
    txtDIGITO.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
    txtCOD_FISA.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
    txtNOMBRE.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
    //ddlCARGO is the DropDownList
    ddlCARGO.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[6].Text);
    lblResult.Visible = false;

    //I know that the DropDownList ist outside the GridView, but i don't know how to access/bind data to it
    DropDownList combo_cargo = GridView2.Rows[index].FindControl("ddlCARGO") as DropDownList;

    if (combo_cargo != null)
    {
        combo_cargo.DataSource = DataAccess.GetAllCargos(); //in GridView default edit mode, this works OK
        combo_cargo.DataTextField = "cargo";
        combo_cargo.DataValueField = "idCARGO";
        combo_cargo.DataBind();
    }

    combo_cargo.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[6].Text));

}
```

The modal html code [.aspx]:

```
 <!-- EDIT Modal Starts here -->

  <div id="editModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                  <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="close"
                             data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h3 id="editModalLabel">Editar Empleado</h3>
                  </div>

                  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEdit" runat="server">

                      <ContentTemplate>

                          <div class="modal-body">

                            <p> Nombre: <asp:TextBox ID="txtNOMBRE" runat="server" columns="40"></asp:TextBox> </p>

                            <p>RUT: <asp:TextBox ID="txtRUT" runat="server" columns="8"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDIGITO" runat="server" columns="1"></asp:TextBox></p>

                            <p>Código Fisa: <asp:TextBox ID="txtCOD_FISA" runat="server" columns="7"></asp:TextBox></p>

                            <%--<p>Cargo: <asp:TextBox ID="txtCARGO" runat="server" columns="7"></asp:TextBox></p>--%>

                          <p>Cargo: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCARGO" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></p>

                            <%-- <p>Estado: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ESTADO" SortExpression="idESTADO">
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlESTADO" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblESTADO" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ESTADO") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                       </asp:TemplateField> </p> --%>

                         </div>

                         <div class="modal-footer">
                              <asp:Label ID="lblResult" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                              <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                              <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                         </div>
                     </ContentTemplate>

                     <Triggers>
                          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView2" EventName="RowCommand" />
                          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
                     </Triggers>

                  </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </div>
      </div>
</div>
<!-- Edit Modal Ends here -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution:

Modal html (.aspx):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCARGO" runat="server" CssClass="hiddencol"></asp:TextBox> <%--data value field (hidden with CSS)--%>

      <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="editModalCargo">Cargo</label>  
      <div class="col-xs-3 input_medio">
          <asp:DropDownList id="editModalCargo" runat="server" name="editModalCargo" class="form-control input-md"/>  <%--data text field--%>
      </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group hiddencol"> <%--field with row id (hidden with CSS)--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" columns="2"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

I've put `OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand"` on  `<asp:GridView>` and created a `<asp:ButtonField>` with `CommandName="editRecord">` to edit the row.

---

Code behind (.aspx.cs):

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("editRecord"))
            {
                GridViewRow gvrow = GridView2.Rows[index];
                txtID.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[17].Text); //Pass value from Gridview's column to <asp:TextBox ID="txtID">                 
                txtCARGO.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[13].Text); //Pass value from Gridview's column to <asp:TextBox ID="txtCARGO">
                lblResult.Visible = false;

                BindEditCargo(txtCARGO.Text);
            }

    }


private void BindEditCargo(string cargoValue) //Populates <asp:DropDownList id="editModalCargo">
    {

        editModalCargo.DataSource = DataAccess.GetAllCargos(); 
        editModalCargo.DataTextField = "cargo";
        editModalCargo.DataValueField = "idCARGO";

        // Bind the data to the control.
        editModalCargo.DataBind();

        // Set the default selected item, if desired.
        editModalCargo.SelectedValue = cargoValue;

    }
```

---

DataAccess.cs:

```
public static DataTable GetAllCargos()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM CARGO";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BRconn"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        return dt;

    }
```

---

To read the value from modal (to pass it to a Update query for example), you can use (in code behind):

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Handles Update Button Click Event
    {
        int idEMPLEADO = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text); //Read value from <asp:TextBox ID="txtID">   
        int idCARGO = Convert.ToInt32(editModalCargo.SelectedValue); //Read value from <asp:DropDownList id="editModalCargo">

        DataAccess.UpdateEmpleado(idEMPLEADO, idCARGO); //Update Query

        BindData(); //Refresh Gridview

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea.

Create a DIV/user control with those controls that you need to edit. 
On ROW click - open the DIV in model (jq you can use) and then either pass the Row content to the Model.open Or pass some unique ID of that ROW and load again from DB the Row corresponding detail. And allow editing there and on Save over there - saving to DB with that unique ID preserved.

Let us know